# Bash format string. Substitute placeholders with values.

Tags: string, bash, string-formatting

I would like to format string using linux bash:

```
"<username>{0}</username><password>{1}</password>".format("user", "pass")
```

Output:

```
<username>user</username><password>pass</password>
```

What is the correct command to do this? I can use any other wildcard instead `{0}` and `{1}`

Comment: Is this line in a file or in a variable?

Comment: line in variable

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From `printf --help`:

> **-v *var***    assign the output to shell variable VAR rather than display it on the standard output

So, what you need to do is just:

```
FMT='<username>%s</username><password>%s</password>'
printf -v VAR "$FMT" user pass
```

Comment: You could highlight that user can also be a variable with `printf "$FMT" $(whoami) 'passphrase'`

Answer (score 7):

Try this sort of [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```
TMPL="<username>\$U</username><password>\$P</password>"
REALNAME="Bobby"
REALPASS="Lamepass"

TMPL=${TMPL/\$U/${REALNAME}}
TMPL=${TMPL/\$P/${REALPASS}}
echo $TMPL
```

Answer (score 2):

The syntax you are using seems to be python. Security aspects aside, you could directly call python:

```
var='"<username>{0}</username><password>{1}</password>".format("user", "pass")'
python3 -c "print($var)"
```

prints

```
<username>user</username><password>pass</password>
```